# Como encontrar o menor valor de um vetor em python?

Tags: python-3.x

Alguém poderia me ajudar com a logica dessa função?

Essa função deve recebe um vetor de inteiros e retornar o menor valor dentro desse vetor.

**Ex:** `minimo([1,2,3,5,8,9,0,-2]) -> -2`

Comment: Porquê reinventar a roda ? `min([1,2,3,5,8,9,0,-2])` ou mais genericamente `min(lista)`

Comment: Esse exercício foi solicitado na matéria de estrutura de dados, por isso não posso utilizar o min.

Comment: Ok então comece por estudar `for` e `if`. Com esses dois consegue fazer o que pretende.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Lógica para obter o menor valor lido do usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286534/l%c3%b3gica-para-obter-o-menor-valor-lido-do-usu%c3%a1rio)

Answer (score 3):

A lógica da sua função seria assim:

Você cria uma variável `minimo` que tem o valor do primeiro elemento da lista (se não quiser usar o mesmo nome da função, chame de `min` ou alguma outra coisa).

Daí você percorre o restante da lista elemento a elemento, substituindo o valor de `minimo` pelo elemento caso ele seja menor que o `minimo` atual.

No final você retorna `minimo`.

Para a função ficar mais resistente a erros você pode no início da função verificar se a lista é vazia, e aí lançar uma exceção ou então retornar um valor especial.

Também pode querer verificar o tipo do parâmetro `lista`, afinal pode não ser uma lista, ou não ser um iterável, ou então não conter inteiros. Essas coisas que podem causar erro em tempo de execução em linguagens dinâmicas.

Para construir essa função você precisa conhecer os seguintes elementos da linguagem: `for`, `if`, listas, *slices* e como criar funções.