# Lógica para obter o menor valor lido do usuário

Tags: python, python-3.x

O que tem de errado com a minha lógica? Não consigo retornar o menor valor

```
def menor(size):
    size = size
    vet = [0] * size
    menor = 0

    for i in range(size):
        vet[i] = int(input('Digite os valores: '))

        if vet[i] > menor:
            menor = vet[i]

    return menor
```

Comment: Se o novo valor for **maior** que o outro valor armazenado, atualizo esse outro valor? Isso é o que o seu código está dizendo, daí o erro.

Answer (score 3):

Numerando as linhas do seu código para facilitar:

```
1. def menor(size):
2.     size = size
3.     vet = [0] * size
4.     menor = 0
5.     for i in range(size):
6.         vet[i] = int(input('Digite os valores: '))
7.         if vet[i] > menor:
8.             menor = vet[i]
9.     return menor
```

- Na linha 1, é definido uma função `menor` que recebe um tamanho `size` (provavelmente inteiro), referente ao número de entradas que será lido do usuário;
- Na linha 2 você define `size = size`, isso não fez o menor sentido. Por a função receber `size` como parâmetro, o objeto já será importado ao escopo e poderá ser utilizado dentro da mesma, não há a necessidade de redefinir o objeto, se é que essa era a intenção;
- Na linha 3, você define um vetor de tamanho `size` iniciado com valores zero. Se você não utilizará todos os valores lidos posteriormente, existe mesmo a necessidade de armazená-los todos? Grosseiramente falando, imagine um programa que lerá 1 milhão de números do usuário... Para obter o menor, você precisa saber todos os valores informados ou apenas o menor?
- Na linha 4 você inicia o valor de `menor` em 0 e, devido à lógica implementada, isso poderá trazer problemas que descreverei mais adiante;
- Na linha 5 você define um laço de repetição para ler todos os valores do usuário. Essa parte está ok;
- Na linha 6 você pede ao usuário para informar um valor e o converte para inteiro. Dado que não seria necessário armazenar os valores em uma lista, bastaria que `vet` fosse um objeto `int` singular, não uma lista;
- Na linha 7 você verifica se o último valor informado é maior que o atual menor valor e, se a condição for satisfeita, atualiza o valor de menor na linha 8. Se você quer o menor valor, por quê atualizá-lo para o maior? Isso também não fez sentido. Basta imaginar que o usuário digitasse apenas números negativos: `[-2, -5, -3, -9]`; assim a condição `vet[i] > menor` jamais seria satisfeita, visto que `menor = 0` e, portanto, o resultado seria 0. Como pode o menor número de uma lista de números negativos ser 0 (e tal valor nem pertence à lista)?
- Linha 9 você retorna o valor final de `menor`;

> Um adendo que vale a pena citar é que não é recomendado utilizar o nome de uma variável igual ao nome da função. No Python não existe a distinção e, quando define `menor = 0`, você está sobrescrevendo o objeto da função dentro do escopo da mesma. Embora neste caso funcione, isso é péssimo para manutenção e impossibilita a utilização de recursos como a recursividade.

Considerando os comentários, o código poderia ser:

```
def menor(tamanho):
    menor_valor = None
    for _ in range(tamanho):
        valor = int(input("Informe um valor: "))
        if menor_valor is None or valor < menor_valor:
            menor_valor = valor
    return menor_valor
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TemptingTidyCalculators)</sup>

Iniciando o valor de `menor_valor` como `None` e adicionando a condição `menor_valor is None` você garante que sempre o menor valor retornado seja um valor informado pelo usuário e, com a condição `valor < menor_valor`, você garante que tal valor seja o menor dentre todos.

Nativamente o Python já possui uma função para isso: [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min). Então seu código poderia ser apenas:

```
valores = (int(input("Informe um valor: ")) for _ in range(tamanho))
menor = min(valores)
```

Outro detalhe importante é que sua função `menor` fere o princípio da unicidade do código, pois possui mais de uma responsabilidade: ler os valores e identificar o menor. O ideal, na maior parte dos casos, seria ter uma função para a leitura dos valores e outra apenas para identificar o menor, então, ao invés de passar o número de valores, passar um objeto iterável que já represente todos eles.

[O que são "unidades de código"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216315/5878)

Answer (score -1):

O problema é que você já inicializa o menor igual a zero, assim só se você imputar números negativos que iria ter um resultado diferente de zero.

Dê uma olhada no código abaixo:

```
def menor(size):
  menor = None

  if size > 0:
    vet = [random.randrange(1, 100) for x in range(size)]
    menor = vet[0]

    for n in vet:
      menor = menor if menor < n else n

  return menor
```

Esta seria uma forma de resolver o seu problema, mas não é a unica, mas agora sabendo o problema do seu código você pode solucionar o seu problema.

Comment: não entendi porque fui negativado

Comment: Deve ter sido por causa da primeira versão da sua resposta

Comment: O problema do código da pergunta não é *apenas* iniciar o valor de `menor` com 0; o problema conseguinte que ele opera se a leitura for **maior** do que o elemento anteriormente armazenado é ainda mais danoso.

Comment: obrigado pelo esclarecimento @JeffersonQuesado